# Dependency management for nodejs that controlls versions of not just modules, but npm and node itself

Tags: node.js, npm

It seems that npm does a good job at managing the dependencies
of modules for a given project, with declarative dependency
management (in the package.json file).

I would like to go one step further, and declaratively
control which version of nodejs and npm from source control
(i.e. specifying these versions in some file that is 
in the project' git repo, just like package.json)

On a freshly deployed machine, I would like to have only these steps :

1) clone a git repo of the nodejs project
2) install or update the versions of npm and nodejs
3) npm install

I woud then use this to have a single step deploy/update
probably a script that does (2) and (3) and that feeds
from a config file that is source controlled.

I'd be perfectly satisfied with a solution that only works on linux, 
or even for a given flavor of linux

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what Nodejitsu does with their [Package.json](https://www.nodejitsu.com/documentation/appendix/package-json/). In particular you will see the following lines:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "v0.8.x"
}
```

Then take a look at the Node Version Manager available [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). There's a reasonable write-up on basic usage [here](http://ghosttx.com/2012/04/nvm-cheat-sheet-node-version-manager/).

Given that your deploys should all have a `package.json` this seems like a pretty straightforward method to achieve what you're looking for. Should be a limited amount of "glue" code and it's clearly possible as Nodejitsu is doing it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried [N](http://github.com/visionmedia/n), and was 
going to try MVN next. Which command will take care of 
ensuring the "engines": {"node": "v0.8.0"} part of package.json ?
Is it a nodejitsu specific tool or is it NVM ? I don't see mention
of it in MVN's docs

Comment: _"Which command will take care of ensuring the "engines": {"node": "v0.8.0"} part of package.json ?"_ There is no command that I know of, this is the part of the code you will have to write. It looks like you should also be able to do this with `N`. Really, it's as simple as looking at the `package.json` and calling `n x.y.z my_starting_file.js`.